# Debug node js in webstorm

Tags: node.js, debugging

I spent lot of time to find out how I can debug simple node.js file in webstorm.
after writing simple api in node.js I stuck at some place and looking for solution where i can debug line by line.
I am using Web-storm editor. 
I will also contribute if find some way.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

---

Steps to Debug Node JS code

---

- Open console and type node(it will open node shell).
- Run process.env
- Copy the contents of the PATH value
- Add an environment variable to Webstorm called PATH that uses this value. It will overwrite the default PATH variable that Webstorm gives your app.

---

How to add environment variable to Webstorm.

---

- Click on file name on right top corner.
- Click on Edit configuration and click Environment Variables.
- Click on + button and paste value of PATH variable value.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7gJq.png)

### Now we are done with setup of debug.

### Steps to debug

- click on debug button on Webstrom
  (it equal to node filename.js which we run on console).
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIFVP.png)

**Place break point in code and hit API through browser/POSTMAN.**