# How do I debug Node apps that end very quickly?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Node app that basically does some work and exits. This happens really fast, maybe in a second, so when I do

```
node --inspect app.js
```

I don't have enough time to open Chrome and set the breakpoint in order to stop the script.

Is there some other way to debug the script, e.g. somehow pre-set the breakpoint or make it stop immediately on the first line?

Comment: **If your IDE is WebStorm** Check this out: [Debug node js in webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052447/debug-node-js-in-webstorm)

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the NodeJs debugger?

[Node Debug](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)

To use it, start Node.js with the inspect argument followed by the path to the script to debug.

eg.

```
$ node inspect myscript.js
```

Have a look at the breakpoint section in particular:-

[Node Debugger Breakpoints](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_breakpoints)

You can include:-

```
setBreakpoint(line)
```

to set breakpoints on specific lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the popular node.js debugging apps available in the link below : 
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/

Using `node-inspect`, you can set a breakpoint on current line or specific line using :

```
setBreakPoint()
```

There are many other options of `setBreakpoint()` depending on your requirement which you can find in the documentation [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_breakpoints)

Alternatively, **I'd suggest using VSCode** which has inbuilt debugger with which you can place a breakpoint in the editor itself. You can debug your node.js app in your IDE instead of opening a chrome web inspector or putting debug logs in the code and it is very simple to configure the app. Just create a launch configuration based on how you launch your node.js app and run it.

`Node.js debugging with VSCode` is clearly explained in their docs [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

You can do the same with WebStorm too but you need a paid license to use the WebStorm compared to VSCode which OpenSource.

Comment: So does it mean that there's no way to debug short-running scripts with Google Chrome?

Comment: @K48 I don't think so, because every time we start a node js app it starts as a seperate process and the chrome inspector uses that process id to be able to debug the app. if it's a short running script, by the time our app is open in chrome and we set the breakpoint, the script is already executed and stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following

`node --inspect-brk app.js`

it will start the process with an active breakpoint at the very beginning of the program.